# How to use a the value returned by a bash function in the if clause of a bash script?

Tags: bash

**Explanation**

The following is the output of a script and its content

```
>> cat /ocpkg/test-1.sh
#!/bin/bash
foo() {
    if [[ 1 -eq 1  ]]; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

foo
echo "foo function call output = $?"

if [[ $(foo) ]] ; then
    echo "return has value 0 so doing something"
else
    echo "return has value 1 so doing another thing"
fi

>> /ocpkg/test-2.sh 
foo function call output = 0
return has value 1 so doing another thing
>> cat /ocpkg/test.sh 
#!/bin/bash
foo() {
    if [[ 1 -eq 0  ]]; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

foo
echo "foo function call output = $?"

if [[ $(foo) ]] ; then
    echo "return has value 0 so doing something"
else
    echo "return has value 1 so doing another thing"
fi

>> /ocpkg/test-2.sh 
foo function call output = 1
return has value 1 so doing another thing
```

As shown in the output above, regardless of the return value of `foo` function, the final output of the script is`return has value 1 so doing another thing`.

**Question**

How can one use the returned value of the function in the if clause, when  the function uses the `return` command, for returning value?

Comment: Just use `if foo; then ...`.

Comment: $(foo) is form of command substitution which means replacing $(foo) with std output. Since you are not echoing anything in function foo, hence else part is getting called in both cases... Try to echo something in foo function and see the behaviour...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
if foo; then
```

This way you are using the exit code of `foo`. With `$()` you are using what `foo` has `echo`ed to sysout.